# Run a subset of Nunit TestCases more than once

Tags: c#, nunit

Currently, I have a base test class that performs a login operation for all my end to end tests:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    [SetUp]
    public void BaseSetUp()
    {
        LoginUser("name", "password");
    }
}
```

In my derived test classes, I use ´TestCase´s:

```
[TestCase("foo")]
[TestCase("bar")]
public void Test(string value)
{
    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

I would like to define an arbitrary amount of users/credentials for each test, i.e. run all TestCases for each user.

Is there any way to accomplish this without polluting all TestCases with credentials and moving the LoginUser method to each test?

Comment: Can you use `TestCaseSource` to have a separate method define your values and users, and provide [TestCaseData](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseData) for each combination?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior It has crossed my mind and I guess it's viable. Was curious about alternatives

Comment: That's kind of the standard way. Any alternatives I can think of don't have any benefits over that approach.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Any thoughts regarding how to handle the login procedure without moving it to each test?

Comment: Same as with any code you don't want to duplicate: Create a helper class that deals with login stuff, and have your tests call out to methods in that class.

Comment: If you are running tests via nunit-console runner and you want the same behaviour on all the tests in an assembly then you can pass the credentials as parameter to nunit-console runner and use that within the base class setup. You can repeat this for each new credential you want to use.